# Cassandra datastore client in Go language

Tags: go, cassandra

Is it possible to write client for Cassandra datastore in Go language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best Cassandra client is currently [github.com/tux21b/gocql](https://github.com/tux21b/gocql), however that's likely to change in the next few months.

Comment: Why is it likely to change?  Do you have a compeditor in mind?

Answer (score 8):

I was browsing today for the same thing and didn't find any client.

However I found a repo on GitHub, it appears somebody is working on Thrift generators for Go: http://github.com/anatol/thrift

Answer (score 4):

[gocql](https://github.com/gocql/gocql) is actively maintained native CQL client library for Cassandra in Go. The original tux21b project was turned into a GitHub organization so that the project could be supported by a core group of maintainers.

If you would prefer something less low level than gocql, you could consider [cqlc](http://relops.com/cqlc), which builds on top of gocql. cqlc generates Go code from your Cassandra schema so that you can write type safe CQL statements in Go with a natural query syntax. It still gives you full access to the underlying gocql API if you need it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to this has changed since the question was first asked.  I believe the current frontrunner in the "Golang Cassandra client" race is Gossie:

https://github.com/carloscm/gossie

There is also another project, cass, but its author recommends Gossie

https://github.com/araddon/cass

Comment: At least as of Aug 3, 2014, Gossie is no longer being developed.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to access Cassandra is via the [Thrift](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/) interface. 
Thrift has generators for C++, C#, Erlang, Haskell, Java, Objective C/Cocoa, OCaml, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, and Squeak. So unfortunately no GO support out of the box.
Take a look at http://github.com/anatol/thrift. Dont know anything about the quality

Answer (score -1):

There is currently no library for Cassandra written in Go. Feel free to start one :)

Comment: There are multiple clients.